# Convert to const int

Tags: c++, c

How can the value of a int be copyed into a new const int??

from this:

```
int start= 343;
```

into this:

```
const int end = start;
```

how can this be done, any example? i really dont know how, please help me out-

Comment: It would be more helpful to explain why you are doing this.

Comment: because i want to know if it possible, if yes.. then how

Comment: -1 because the "code" you've provided answers your own question.  Provide better code so that we may understand what the real problem is.

Comment: -1 because you can't make up your mind about which language you are using. Is it C or is it C++? They are not the same.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan anyway it's ok for both languages, he's new let's be nice with him.

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
int start = 343;
const int end = start;
```

If you want to be sure `end` is const, try modifying it:

```
end++; // Compile error!
```

Comment: Nothing changed, it still a int instead of const int

Comment: @user1341993 No, `end` is a `const int`... That's what the `const int` in front of it means.

Comment: +1, you may add that `end` should be declared at block scope.

Comment: @AhmedJolani:  Obv.  They wouldn't be very `const` if you could reassign them, now would they?

Comment: @user1341993 it is a `const int`, as any attempt to modify it will show.

Comment: @user1341993: You should be clear on what you want, my feeling is that you might be looking for a compile time constant (constant expression) that you can use to, say, initialize an array? Your problem is that instead of stating your problem you assume that you *know* what the solution is and are asking for that. A constant and a compile time constant (also known as constant expression) are **not** the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++, you can set a constant member variable at runtime:

```
class M
{ 
    public: 
      M(int number) : mNumber(number)
      {
      }
    const int mNumber;
};
```

Comment: You're not exactly wrong, but you're unnecessarily complicating matters.

Comment: And without a class also, `int start; scanf("%d", &start); const int end = start;` but any latter change to end is not allowed, I was wrong in my first answer sorry I let do this.